# If-else condition with Realtime firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, if-statement, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to use if/else on firebase's realtime results? My database looks like this:

[image]

Previously I've tried it and it works if the result of both "waktu" is same, == recent.

but what I want is if one of the values "waktu" == recent, then "Hasil" = 0, if both of "time" nothing is equal to "Recent", then the value "Hasil" = 0.

```
if ("Recent" == (one of) "waktu") {
   Hasil : "1";
} else {
   Hasil : "0";
}
```

This is my code before, which value "Result" = 1, if both "waktu" values == recent. but i want if one values of "waktu" == Recent.

```js
      var recent = "";
      var root = firebase.database().ref();

      root.child("Time").on('value', (snapshot) => {
        recent = snapshot.val().Recent;
      });

      root.child("jadwal-pakan").on('value', (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach(jadwal_waktu => {
          if (jadwal_waktu.child("waktu").val() == recent) {
            root.update({
              Keadaan: {
                Hasil: 1
              }
            });
          } else {
            root.update({
              Keadaan: {
                Hasil: 0
              }
            });
          }
        })
      })
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the timing of when the code executes. Since all data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, your `recent = snapshot.val().Recent` may run after `if (jadwal_waktu.child("waktu").val() == recent) {` has run.

To ensure this is guaranteed, you'll need to nest the listeners like this:

```
root.child("Time").on('value', (snapshot) => {
  recent = snapshot.val().Recent;
  root.child("jadwal-pakan").on('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach(jadwal_waktu => {
      if (jadwal_waktu.child("waktu").val() == recent) {
        root.update({
          Keadaan: {
            Hasil: 1
          }
        });
      } else {
        root.update({
          Keadaan: {
            Hasil: 0
          }
        });
      }
    })
  })
});
```

Now there's no chance of the statements executing out of order, and the `if (jadwal_waktu.child("waktu").val() == recent) {` will work as expected.

Comment: Thankyou for the response. I've tried it, but the result is same, "Result" = 1, if the value of both "waktu" is the same == "Recent", not one of them ("waktu").

Comment: what I want like this, for example:
if ("Recent" == ("waktu 1" || "waktu 2")) {
   Hasil : "1";
} else {
   Hasil : "0";
}

Comment: Btw it's worked when I removed the "else" function and used double "if (==) and  (!=)" function, thank you so much, Frank. :)